# sh + how to run command and set it into parameter ( VAL )

Tags: linux, shell-script, sh

please take look on the following commands down, ( the shell is **sh** )

something not clearly for me

when I run -  **eval echo \$arr$n** , I get the value **a** as expected

so why:  **VAL=`eval echo \$arr$n`** , and **echo $VAL** not print the same value **a** ?

set a value in arr1

```
# n=1
# eval arr$n=a
```

print a value from arr1

```
# n=1
# eval echo \$arr$n
  a
```

set **eval echo \$arr$n**  in to **VAL** , and print **$VAL**

```
# VAL=` eval echo \$arr$n `
# echo $VAL
{*}1
```

what need to fix in the command - **VAL=`eval echo \$arr$n`** , so when I do **echo $VAL** I will get the value **a**  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `$()` instead of back quotes:

```
VAL=$(eval echo \$arr$n)
```

Comment: Or double-escape in the backticks: VAL=\`eval echo \\\$arr\$n`

Comment: `VAL=\`eval echo \\$arr$n\`` seems to be enough.